# Symfony 2 : Set a parameter globally based on Request

Tags: php, symfony

I will try to be *very* specific here.

Im using [BazingaGeocoderBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaGeocoderBundle) Integration of the [Geocoder-php](http://geocoder-php.org/) library into Symfony2.
On the config.yml you can set the geolocation Providers with their params

**config.yml**

```
bazinga_geocoder:
    providers:
        google_maps:
            locale: en
            region: US
```

Also i have a service listener, used to know which api should i use based on domain name. If someone access i will access the specific api url

```
www.domain.us -> api.en.anotherdomain.com
www.domain.it -> api.it.anotherimaginarydomain.com
```

The service listener is setted on config.yml

```
services:
    kernel.listener.domain_listener:
        class: MyOwn\Bundle\WebBundle\Listener\DomainListener
        arguments:
        - %tld_allowed%
        tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onDomainGet }
```

On everyrequest i set a session value with the corresponding api domain.

I want to be able to specify the bazinga_geocoder params, so i can set the google_maps provider parameters (locale, region) based on the domain accessed.

How can i do that? im on the wrong path?

Comment: Nice and well explained question, +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how this bundle works, but looking at the code:

- When a new provider is found (through the configuration), the [extension](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaGeocoderBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/BazingaGeocoderExtension.php#L196) will create a new `Definition` with id `bazinga_geocoder.provider.$name`
- The definition is going to have a tag `bazinga_geocoder.provider` and a **private** visibility
- The [compiler pass](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaGeocoderBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddProvidersPass.php#L47) will look for services tagged as `bazinga_geocoder.provider` and calls `registerProvider` on `bazinga_geocoder.geocoder` service, that is the [`Geocoder`](https://github.com/willdurand/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Geocoder/Geocoder.php).

Maybe this may work: inject the `bazinga_geocoder.provider.google_maps` service in your request listener, then call `$provider->setLocale($locale)`. I don't know hot to set the region, as there isn't a setter in the [`AbstractProvider`](https://github.com/willdurand/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Geocoder/Provider/AbstractProvider.php) class (neither in [`GoogleMapsProvider`](https://github.com/willdurand/Geocoder/blob/master/src/Geocoder/Provider/GoogleMapsProvider.php)).

A "brutal" solution would be creating a new `GoogleMapsProvider` instance in the request listener, adding it to the geocoder. The listener should accept these services:

- `bazinga_geocoder.geocoder.adapter`
- `bazinga_geocoder.geocoder`

That is:

```
use Geocoder\Geocoder;
use Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMapsProvider;
use Geocoder\HttpAdapter\HttpAdapterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    private $adapter;
    private $geo;

    public function __construct(HttpAdapterInterface $adapter, Geocoder $geo)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->geo = $geo;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // Get locale and region in some way

        // Create and register the provider, dynamically
        $provider = new GoogleMapsProvider($this->adapter, $locale, $region);
        $this->geo->registerProvider($provider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gremo! I pick the "brutal" solution. Its not the best, but another approach will be awful too. The only really CLEAN solution i see is a rewrite of the bundle itself, to support all of this.